# Threading with Tkinter done right (with or without queues)

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, tkinter, queue

i have a much more advanced code, but it all comes to this simple example:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def destroyPrint():
    global printOut
    try:
        printOut.destroy()
    except:
        pass


def sendData():
    global new
    global printOut
    for i in range(6):
        destroyPrint()
        time.sleep(1)
        printOut=Label(new,text=i,font=('arial',15,'bold'))
        printOut.place(x=300,y=500)


def newWindow():
    global new
    print("ok")
    new=Toplevel()
    new.minsize(800,600)
    functionButton=Button(new,text="Send me",width=20,height=20, command=sendData)
    functionButton.place(x=300,y=150)


main = Tk()
main.minsize(800, 600)
menu=Button(main,text="Send data",width=20,height=20, command=newWindow)
menu.place(x=300,y=150)
mainloop()
```

In this simple example, i want to start sendData function, which will update printOut Label accordingly on every loop iteration. We all know that it doesn't, and that it hangs, until function is done, and prints last number (5).

I tried countless examples with threading and queueing, and i am failing badly.
Please, just simple clarification on this example, how to do threading correctly when you have Tkinter elements in a function that needs to be performed in another thread.

I am really getting frustrated here and i spent last 2 days on this step...

Comment: does your real code do more than display data to the screen? You may or may not need threading depending on what you're really wanting to do.

Comment: It connects to a number of hosts via socket. Problem is when server is not running on hosts and while client tries to connect...gui hangs...it definitely needs threading.

Comment: Basicaly i want it to show data on screen...and that GUI doesn't hang while it tries to connect

Answer (score 2):

You have to add update_idletasks() to update the label.  Instead of destroying and creating, just update the text , and use after() in Tkinter instead of sleep as it spawns a new process whereas time.sleep() hangs the program while sleeping.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

def sendData():
    global new
    ##global printOut
    printOut=Label(new,text="0",font=('arial',15,'bold'))
    printOut.place(x=300,y=500)
    for x in range(6):
        ##destroyPrint()
        printOut.config(text=str(x))
        new.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)

def newWindow():
    global new
    print("ok")
    new=Toplevel()
    new.minsize(800,600)
    functionButton=Button(new,text="Send me",width=20,
                  height=20, command=sendData)
    functionButton.place(x=300,y=150)


main = Tk()
main.minsize(800, 600)
menu=Button(main,text="Send data",width=20,height=20, command=newWindow)
menu.place(x=300,y=150)
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cool, and now if i could only get "new" window responsive at all times? I think you need threading for that...

Comment: Time to learn classes. An instance attribute/variable is available throughout the class name space and can be accessed anywhere within the class.

Comment: Your comment tells what exactly? That it can be done only via classes? That same thing isn't true for plain functions via global variables? If i transfer my example to a class will you show me a solution that i am after?